# How does the second section of the newsletter generate?

Tags: support, newsletter

There are 3 sections in the newsletter. The second section is "Greatest hits from previous weeks". How does it generate?

Comment: Did you just use a sock puppet account to edit and approved your own edit? This is NOT a good thing.

Comment: Sorry. I just want to know how does someone else review my suggested edit. And as a result, I didn't modify my question. It won't happen again. :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure this section is being generated on the basis of `{se-site}/questions/greatest-hits` (i.e. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/greatest-hits), but only the questions from the "previous weeks" are taken.

The sidebar explains (or at least tries to do it) the meaning of "greatest hits":

> Questions that got a large amount of views or a large amount of feedback.

(more info on greatest hits [there](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/stack-exchanges-greatest-hits/))